# Reapply gitignore rules for the whole history

Tags: git

This is three parts this is a more step-by-step question than [Make Git rebuild history using the current .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39178676/make-git-rebuild-history-using-the-current-gitignore)

1. I was wondering if it is possible to do a rebase to some early point in history and set the `.gitignore` rules there such that it carries it all the way to the top.  The way I do it is `git checkout KNOWN_COMMIT_WITH_PROPER_GITIGNORE .gitignore && git rebase --continue`
2. Apply the removal of ignored files for each commit in the history while `--preserve-merges` https://stackoverflow.com/a/19757964/242042.   I am thinking this can be done in a similar way of `git-filter-branch`
3. Create an alias that would do this operation

Key thing is that this needs to be based on the `.gitignore` that could've changed over time and I want a specific version of the `.gitignore` file applied to the first commit and applied through the rest of history.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Completely remove file from all Git repository commit history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/completely-remove-file-from-all-git-repository-commit-history)

Comment: Close but I wanted it to apply the removal based on the .gitignore files.

Comment: It's tricky, but I believe you can do this with `git filter-branch`. I think I even provided code to do it in some earlier StackOverflow posting.

Comment: Maybe you can point to the posting, because the ones I had found I put in there already.

Comment: Found it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43463687/1256452 (the trick was google search for `git filter-branch gitignore torek site:stackoverflow.com`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can combine ['git filter-branch'](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) with ['git ls-files'](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files). Something like this:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached `git ls-files --exclude-standard -i`'
```

I.e., filter the branch and modify index; for every commit list ignored files in the index and remove them from the index.

PS. But please make a backup before experimenting.